# 12 hr time format in sql like.. 02:32:00 PM

Tags: sql-server

How can I get the time like  02:32:00 PM in sql server?

I can get 24 hr with the following code.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), getdate(), 108)
```

But I want pure hh:mm:ss tt not with milliseconds.

I found the one with milliseconds.

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 109)
```

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(STUFF(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(26), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 109), 14),9, 4, ' ')),11)
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for a full listing of **all supported** styles / formats for date/time conversion using `CONVERT`.

There doesn't seem to be an exact match for what you're looking for, I'm afraid. You'll have to use some other, supported format and possibly do some string manipulation on the result yourself.

Those are **all** the supported formats - there is no way I'm aware of to extend this (other than writing a SQL CLR module yourself and plugging it into SQL Server).